# How to change the date and time in REST API for comments?

Tags: rest-api, api, date, date-time, wp-api

```
/**
 * Add a Formatted Date to the WordPress REST API JSON Post Object
 *
 */
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
   register_rest_field(
      array('comment'),
      'formatted_date',
      array(
         'get_callback' => function() {
            return get_the_date();
         },
         'update_callback' => null,
         'schema' => null,
      )
   );
});
```

This is not working for me. I am constantly getting the following in my JSON:

```
"formatted_date":false,"
```

How can I show it in a format like: `"28 November 2021, 15:00"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I would be careful modifying existing endpoints, but you could try using the object passed into the callback, e.g.:

```
'get_callback' => function( $object ) {
    return date_i18n( __( 'j. F Y, H:i', 'wpse' ), strtotime( $object['date'] ) );
 },
```

Comment: May I ask why you say that? Want to learn from it. My alternative is keep it as-is, but I get things like: "date_gmt":"2021-11-17T10:37:40". This is not super nice.

Comment: Strictly we should change the API version number if the API changes, right? So a custom endpoint might be the way in some cases. One can even override existing fields this way. This was more of a general remark (for possibly other readers in the future), but the use cases are very different, some APIs might be very popular, used  by many apps that depend on a given schema and version and some might be only for simple localhost testing, so do what suits you and your project :-)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it works like a charm.